# $(f \circ g)(x) = \sin (x^{1/2})^2, \; (g \circ f)(x) = | \sin x |$

Tags: functions, absolute-value

If

> $(f \circ g)(x) = \sin (\sqrt{x})^2$
>
> $(g \circ f)(x) = | \sin x |$

Find $f(x)$ , $g(x)$.

I'm told there are 2 solutions.

I do not have an idea of how to approach these questions. Would you please also give the required line of thought.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute value must have come from $|x|=(x^2)^{1/2}$ since these powers appear in the other function.
Also, it seems that the square is always outside the sine whereas the square root is inside in $f\circ g$ but outside in $g\circ f$.
This suggests that the square and the sine are in one function and the square root is in the other.
Indeed, one example is given by $g(t)=t^{1/2}$ and $f(t)=\sin^2(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The absolute value doesn't come out of nowhere, so we can rewrite $g\circ f=\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}$.

Can you find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ now?

Comment: Thank you. Through that i could figure out that g(x)= x^.5 and f(x) = (sinx)^2  . It was mostly intuitive and trial and error. Is there a set way of solving such questions??